# Order multiple rows in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
ID EPOCH
B    2
B    3
A    1
A    2
A    3
C    0
```

and what I would like to do is to order it by the ID first appearance date (i.e. the minimum value of EPOCH for each ID) so that I get

```
ID EPOCH
C    0
A    1
A    2
A    3
B    2
B    3
```

I managed only to order the data frame according to Epoch and than ID

```
df[order(df$EPOCH,df$ID),]
```

but than it is no more clustered by ID, i.e.

```
C  0
A  1
A  2
B  2
A  3
B  3
```

Many thanks

Comment: Yes but in this way I get                                                          C  0
A  1
A  2
B  2
A  3
B  3

Comment: Jan has the answer below. Sorry I didn't read more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a column with the minimum `EPOCH` for each `ID` to the `data.frame`:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("ID EPOCH
B    2
B    3
A    1
A    2
A    3
C    0"), header=TRUE)

a <- aggregate(data$EPOCH, data["ID"], min)
names(a)[2] <- "min_EPOCH"

data <- merge(data, a)
```

Then sort on that new column:

```
o <- order(data$min_EPOCH, data$ID, data$EPOCH)
data[o, ]
```